# Associate string with image

Tags: jquery

I currently have the code below which successfully sets a random image from an array as `.wrapper`'s background. I'd like to have another variable (string) that is permanently paired with each specific image so that when an image is randomly selected, its particular string is also passed in. So if `foo.jpg` is randomly selected, variable `x` is set to 'foo', but if `bar.jpg` is randomly selected, variable `x` is set to 'bar'.

Any ideas how this can be achieved? Possibly with a JSON object?

my code:

```
var images = ["foo.jpg", "bar.jpg", "baz.jpg", "qux.jpg"];
function getImage() {
        return images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
}
$('.wrapper').css({
    'background' : 'url(' + getImage() + ') no-repeat center center fixed'
});
```

Let me know any questions you may have.

Thanks

Comment: The question is not clear. It would be better if you describe what you're trying to do

Comment: I am trying to pass a string relevant to the randomly selected background image so that I can display it.

Comment: FYI, `JSON` is a textual data definition format.  Perhaps what you meant was a `Javascript object`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your array an array of objects instead where each object in the array contains both the url and the tag.  You randomly select one of the objects and can then separately access both the url and the tag:

```
var images = [
    {url: "foo.jpg", tag: "foo"}, 
    {url: "bar.jpg", tag: "bar"}, 
    {url; "baz.jpg", tag: "baz"},
    {url: "qux.jpg", tag: "qux"}
];

function getNum() {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
}
var item = images[getNum()];
$('.wrapper').css({
    'background' : 'url(' + item.url + ') no-repeat center center fixed'
}).html(item.tag);
```

Or, if the tag is always just the base of the image name so you can parse it out of the url, you could do this:

```
var images = ["foo.jpg", "bar.jpg", "baz.jpg", "qux.jpg"];
function getNum() {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
}
var num = getNum();
$('.wrapper').css({
    'background' : 'url(' + images[num] + ') no-repeat center center fixed'
}).html(images[num].replace(/\.jpg$/, ""));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using parallel arrays.

```
var images = ["foo.jpg", "bar.jpg", "baz.jpg", "qux.jpg"];
var x      = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "qux"];
function getNum() {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
}
var num = getNum();
$('.wrapper').css({
    'background' : 'url(' + images[num] + ') no-repeat center center fixed'
}).html(x[num]);
```